# How to detect voicemail on freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch, voicemail

I am using freeswitch and I would like to detect voicemail on phone which I call. 
Let's assume I call number xxx-xxx-xxx and if can't talk with owner of that number I would like to know it. Is that possible? As far I have tried to recognize the special sound but actually efectiveness of that solution is really low because many owners have their own message recoded on voicemail.

Comment: Did you try `mod_avmd`?

Comment: Yes but accuracy is so poor. I would even say that it's uselles.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a commercial module (mod_com_amd) that will do that for you. It's available directly from the FreeSWITCH site: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_com_amd

Comment: Have you ever used it? What is a accuracy of detecting voicemail? It seems like it analyze the sound, not just waiting for beep signal (which is really bad idea nowadays).